# Нужна запятая перед словом "такие" и словом "как"?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, как

"В пресс-службе Россельхознадзора заявили о том, что без должной биологической защиты от вирусов (?) такие заболевания (?) как птичий грипп и АЧС могут начать мутировать".
Нужна ли запятая перед словами "такие" и "как"? Если да, то можете объяснить почему?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Оборот с союзом КАК обособляется:

*В пресс-службе Россельхознадзора заявили о том, что без должной биологической защиты от вирусов  такие заболевания, **как птичий грипп и АЧС**, могут начать мутировать.*

**Розенталь:** http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=147#pp147

3. Сравнительный оборот с союзом как выделяется запятыми в следующих случаях:

2) если в основной части предложения имеется **указательное слово** (так, такой, тот, столь): Нигде при взаимной встрече не раскланиваются так благородно и непринуждённо, как на Невском проспекте (Г.); …Я всё сделаю, чтобы стать такой, как она.

Но: **Наша** группа досрочно сдала все зачёты, **так же как параллельная** — без расчленения сложного союза;

Для сравнения: *В пресс-службе Россельхознадзора заявили о том, что без должной биологической защиты от вирусов **некоторые** заболевания, **такие как птичий грипп и АЧС**,  могут начать мутировать.*

Здесь указательное слово включено в оборот.